# pod lib lint --include-podspecs ignores dependency to subspec of another pod

Tags: cocoapods

I have two pods (PodA and PodB) where PodA has a dependency to a subspec of PodB.

Both pods are in the same repository and added as development pods to the same Xcode project. None of them is released so far.

**podspec PodA:**

```
s.source_files = 'PodA/**/*.{swift}'
s.dependency 'PodB/Logic'
```

**podspec PodB:**

```
s.default_subspec = 'UI'

s.subspec "Logic" do |sp|
  sp.source_files = 'PodB/Logic/**/*.{swift}'
end

s.subspec "UI" do |sp|
  sp.source_files = 'PodB/UI/**/*.{swift}'
  sp.dependency 'PodB/Logic'
end
```

**Linting PodA:**

```
$ pod lib lint PodA.podspec --include-podspecs='*.podspec' --no-clean
```

Because the app project includes PodA and PodB with all subspecs, it's possible to access implementation from 'PodB/UI' where no dependency should exist. This should be covered by running pod lib lint.

While linting PodA the dependency to 'PodB/Logic' is ignored and instead the full PodB will be used during the linting. Therefore the linting is successful, even it uses "inaccessible" code from 'PodB/UI'.

**Note:** If i create a release of PodB first, and run the linting for PodA, it works like expected and takes the subspecs of PodB into account

Is this intended behavior? Is there any way to properly lint PodA without releasing PodB first?